# Float Right property in css is not working

Tags: html, css

I want to allign the send button to right. But it's not working.

css:

```
 input.textarea {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        z-index: 99;
        background: #fafafa;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        padding-left: 55px;
        padding-right: 55px;
        color: #666;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    .send-btn {
      float: right!important;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: right;
        bottom: 8px;
        left: 7px;
        width: 34px;
        height: 34px;
        background-image: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/dark-action-bar-2/96/send-512.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: 100;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

So please help me in solve this error..

Thank you...                                                                                                             \

.

Comment: Float right does nothing if you have position fixed ... just change left for right

Comment: Lmfaooo @connexo I am noob

Comment: Ohk let me try @DaniP

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

In *.send-btn* remove *position: fixed;*

Comment: it's getting invisible xD

Answer (score 0):

I changed the

```
left: 7px;
```

to

```
left: 90%
```

and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Flexbox. Create a parent container which holds the input & button - `.input-container` and apply `display: flex;` property with `align-items: center;` (to arrange items in the center vertically).

And place the `input.textarea` and `.send-btn` as its items (child).

Please have a look at the code below.

```css
/* New container with flex properties */
.input-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
  display: flex; /* Flex Property */
  align-items: center; /* Alignining items center vertically */
  background: #fafafa; /* Applying BG to container instead of textfield */
}

/* Modifications to input */
input.textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  background: transparent;
  
  /* Old styles */
  z-index: 99; border: none; outline: none; color: #666; font-weight: 400;
}

.send-btn {
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 34px;
  
  /* Old styles */
  background-image: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/dark-action-bar-2/96/send-512.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; z-index: 100; cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="text" class="textarea" value="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s..." />
  <button class="send-btn"></button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!